# How to stop the user in entering text for h:inputText?

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.2 - My Faces Implementation. I have a form , I use h:inputText to display few values. There are 2 input boxes which should not be edited but shown to the user and should be submitted to the server when the submit it clicked. I tried readonly="true" and disabled="true", both did not solve the purpose! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

The `readonly="true"` should suit your requirements. The text will be uneditable and the value will be submitted to the server.

The `disabled="true"` don't suit your requirements. The text will indeed be uneditable, but the value won't be submitted to the server.

Note that when you use them *both*, then the value won't be submitted at all. Also when there's a `rendered` attribute on it or one of its parents which evaluates to `false` during form submit, then the value won't be gathered during apply request values phase of the form submit request.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.
readonly="true" did not work.
disabled="true" worked. Please edit, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: No, readonly should suit your requirements. Aren't you using some bean property for that which should be retained in the subsequent request? E.g. `readonly="#{bean.readonly}"`? If so, you know the answer. If not, then you need to elaborate "did not work" in more detail. Explain it in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective.

Comment: <h:inputText styleClass="disabledfield" size="3" disabled="true"
 id="editIBD" value="#{someBean.someValue}">

I am using like this, and now the values are not submitted!!!

Comment: I tried as you suggesed defaulting readOnly to true in the Bean.It does not help. FYI , I am populating the values of these fields using Javascript in the front end and I could see them when populated in the screen but in the debug JSF Life cycle phases-sysouts(INVOKE APPLICATION), I could not!!! Whats wrong?

Comment: If `disabled="true"` then the value will indeed never be submitted as I stated in my answer. Changing it to `disabled="false"`  in JS is not enough. It's still `disabled="true"` in JSF component tree in the server side. You need to change it in the server side as well. I.e. change the value using JSF/Java, not JS.

Comment: I wasn't able to use either of them successfully. For Now , I have corresponding hiddenInput and make the non-Hidden as readonly="true" , that way i get the value in the server side and the user is not allowed to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `readonly = "true"` doesn't submit value to server, I suggest `readonly= "#{facesContext.renderResponse}"`, it works well for me