# Primefaces Form with 2 buttons dont update

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces

I have a form that has an inputtext where the operator enters the clientid and click on "search", when the search is done the other fields in the form are populated correctly.

Then I have the button "new record"  that calls a procedure that creates another object (not a customer) and needs to persist it, when the other object is created in the bean it takes every field from the form except a timestamp.

When the object is persisted only the timestamp is in the DB, all the form values are set to null.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:outputText value="Customer number" /> 
    <h:inputText id="cIdentidad" value="#{custBean.custID}" />
    <p:commandButton  process="@all" update="@all"  action="#{custBean.populateFields(custBean.custID)}" value="Search" />               
    <p:growl />

    <h:panelGrid id="newCust" columns="2" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <h:outputText value="Name" /> 
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{custBean.name}" disabled="true"/>
        <h:outputText value="more fields" /> 
        <h:inputText id="nroAgenda" value="#{custBean.morefields}" disabled="true"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton  process="@all" update="@all"  action="#{custBean.newRecord()}" value="New record" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: the bean is sessionscoped

Answer (score 1):

The `h:inputText`'s are disabled, so the value will not be submitted to the server. Maybe you're looking for `readonly="true"`.

Also I would'nt use `@all` everywhere but rather `@form`. `update="@all"` has a special [meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes).

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062639/how-to-stop-the-user-in-entering-text-for-hinputtext) answer.